# DataTables - RowReorder not printing the updated row order

Tags: jquery, datatables

After a row has been reordered, I would like to get the updated row order, but after all solutions tried, the original row order prints every time. How can I get the updated row order?

The docs suggest using `dataTable.rows({ order: 'updated' }).data()`, but it's not working.

Refer: [DataTables](https://datatables.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Try `applied` instead of <strike>`updated`</strike>

`table.rows({ order: 'applied' }).data()`

**Possible values** - `'current', 'applied', 'index',  'original'`

More info on [selector-modifier](https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier#Options)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I also tried all those options when worked through the documentation.

Comment: @deanwilliammills check which version are you using?